# Show # of results next to filter

Tags: jquery, filter

The function below allows users to filter products by `data-attributes`, and accommodates filtering by multiple values simultaneously. How can I display the number of potential results `on load` next to each option? Ideally I'd also like to display the total number of results for each search they run.

I've posted a fiddle with a working example of the function here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/hSwcr/1/

```
    var selected = { color: [], style: [] };   
    $('.filterOptions').on("change", ":checkbox", function (e) {
        var type = $(e.delegateTarget).data("type");
        var $this = $(this);
        var attrValue = $this.data(type);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected[type].splice(selected[type].indexOf(attrValue),1);
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected[type].push(attrValue);
        }            
        var checked = $(":checked", ".filterOptions");            
        // show all of the available options if...
        if (checked.length == 0 || checked.filter(".all").length > 0) {
            $('#content').find('*').show();
        } 
        else {
            $("#content").find("*").hide();
            for (var key in selected) {
                $.each(selected[key], function(index,item) {
                    $('#content').find('[data-' + key + ' *="' + item + '"]').show();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current implementation, you can do this in the "for in" loop within checkbox change event handler:

```
for (var key in selected) {
            $.each(selected[key], function(index,item) {
                var $products = $('#content').find('[data-' + key + ' *="' + item + '"]'),
                    totalCount = $products.length;

                $.each($products, function(idx, product){
                      //implement logic for running count for product options                    
                });

                //implement logic to append count to options and display totalCount


                $products.show();
            });
        }
```

**However** I would recommend taking a step back and creating a JS Object Literal for all your products with attribute and attribute values so that you can separate your data from your UI.  For your data you can use a library like underscore.js to query your data for total results, filter for products, and calculate potential total per option.  For your UI (HTML), you can use a templating framework like mustache.js, handlebars.js, knockout.js, etc. to bind your queried data. IMHO it will make your life easier going forward.

Example JS Object:

```
{ products: [
    {
        product: "Sleeveless, V-Neck, Black, Red", 
        attributes : [
         {
               attributeName: "color",
               attributeValue: "Red"
         },
         {
               attributeName: "color",
               attributeValue: "Black"
         },
         {
               attributeName: "style",
               attributeValue: "V-Neck"
         },
         {
               attributeName: "style",
               attributeValue: "Sleeveless"
         }
      ]
  },

  //etc.....

  ]
}
```

Comment: I'll try to create the logic tomorrow so I can test your script :-) I'm definitely open to using a library or template because I'll be filtering by a lot of different data-attributes, but the one that I looked at - Backbone - seemed like it would take a while to figure out, and the Filtrify plugin was incredibly easy too use but couldn't be incorporated into menu items. Are any of the ones you suggested fairly simple to use?

Comment: Underscore.js is actually a part of backbone (written by the same person responsible for for backbone).. It should be easier as it is lightweight and its primary purpose is to query collections.  Documentation is good too.  I would say mustache.js is the easiest templating framework (documentation is  straight forward).

Comment: That is incredibly helpful :-D I'll probably check out Underscore.js first, since it (since I'm assuming that would make it easy to later transition to backbone). On a separate note, I'd love to accept your answer :-) Is there an easy way for me to run the script that you posted (just so that I can confirm that it works)?

Comment: The script as provided will not run as it contains psuedo code (i.e., I have commented where to implement logic).  I was hoping it offered guidance if you went with your current implementation as it would take quite a bit of code to build out what you are requesting.  I can elaborate on it or if you can provide me a question you have concerning it I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I know how much SO is used by people researching an issue so I usually try to test the code before accepting it, but both your answer and advice have been really helpful so I'm assuming that others will feel that way too ;-) I'm going to look into Underscore & Mustache, and I may take you up on your offer if I end up writing the script myself and need some help :-)